# Format code instructions (CS Theory)

Tags: spacing

I'm new to LATEX and having a tough time doing my homework and properly formatting code. As you see, the spacing is out of whack and the beginning of each line for each instruction does not line up. Could anyone recommend a better way to make sure they line up? Thanks.

P.S. - I tried using `\quad`, but it doesn't seem to work when it is the first instruction on a line in a LATEX document.

```
\indent \indent $IF\ Z_1 \neq 0\ GOTO \ C$\\
$[B]$ \indent $X \leftarrow X - 1$\\
\indent \indent $Y \leftarrow Y + 1$\
```

Rendering:

[image: Rendering]

Comment: you might want to look at (one of the) packages for setting algorithms/pseudocode `algorithm` `algorithmicx` etc (lots of examples on this site)

Comment: See [Print programs with its proper syntax](http://goo.gl/kimkM).